# Рефакторинг в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

Допустим, есть модель, которая была сгенерирована из БД.
С использованием этой модели был написан код.

В один момент возникает потребность сменить название колонки в БД.

Если я сменю название колонки и выполню обновление из БД, то в сущности появится новое свойство.

В итоге сущность будет иметь 2 свойства: свойство со старым именем, и свойство с актуальным именем.

Как мне отрефакторить сам код, что бы там где использовалось старое свойство, стало использоваться новое?

Comment: Вы уверены, что старое свойство не пропадёт? Вы используете code first или db first? Думаю, вам нужны [миграции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj591621.aspx).

Comment: Использую db first

Comment: Ну так тогда поменяйте базу и удалите entity-классы и перегенерируйте их, делов-то!

Comment: @VladD, так если перегенерировать классы, то разве пол кода не придет в негодность, так где использовалось это свойство ? Или студия поймет и переименует его сама?

Comment: Не, не переименует. Тогда перед тем, как удалять, просто переименуйте свойство через F2 (или Edit -> Refactor -> Rename).

Answer (score 1):

Если код компилируемый исключительно - то помечаете старое свойство аттрибутом `Obsolete` и исправляете по мере времени и возможностей предупреждения.

Если же есть какие то неудобные завязки, которые так просто не найти - можно просто старое свойство теперь перенаправлять на новое, что то типа

`ObsoleteProperty { get { return NewProperty; } set { NewProperty = value; } }`